# Ошибка при нажатии на Button

Tags: android-sdk, android-studio, activity, android

Еще раз здравствуйте, создал я калькулятор, но при нажатии на любую из операций  * / - + два раза, например запустили и сразу нажали два раза на плюс, выскакивает ошибка и выкидывает из приложения, в чем дело?

MainActivity.class

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText editText;
private float NumberBf;
private String Operation;

private List<Button> buttons;
private static final int[] idList = {R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3,
        R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7,
        R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.buttonPluss, R.id.buttonClear,
        R.id.buttonDilenie, R.id.buttonTochka, R.id.buttonRavno,
        R.id.buttonYmnog, R.id.buttonMinus};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setEnabled(false);

    buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    for(int id : idList){
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()){
                    case R.id.buttonClear: //clear screen
                        editText.setText("0");
                        NumberBf = 0;
                        Operation = "";
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonPluss: //function Add
                        mMath("+");
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonMinus:
                        mMath("-");
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonYmnog:
                        mMath("*");
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonDilenie:
                        mMath("/");
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonRavno:
                        mResult();
                        break;
                    default:
                        String numb = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
                        getKeyboard(numb);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void getKeyboard(String str){
    String ScrCurrent = editText.getText().toString();
    if(ScrCurrent.equals("0")){
        ScrCurrent = "";
    }
    ScrCurrent += str;
    editText.setText(ScrCurrent);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void mResult(){
    float NumAf = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString());
    float result = 0;
        if(Operation.equals("+")){
            result = NumAf + NumberBf;
        }

        if(Operation.equals("-")){
            result = NumberBf - NumAf;
        }

        if(Operation.equals("*")){
            result = NumAf * NumberBf;
        }

        if(Operation.equals("/")){
            result = NumberBf / NumAf;
        }
        editText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

public void mMath(String str){
    NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString()); // save the screen
    Operation = str; //save operation
    editText.setText(""); //clear screen
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Добавьте Stacktrace ошибки

Comment: А еще названия переменных пишутся с маленькой буквы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а кто проверять будет в этом методе ?

```
public void mMath(String str){
    NumberBf = Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString()); // save the screen
    Operation = str; //save operation
    editText.setText(""); //clear screen
}
```

если при старте тут пусто editText.getText().toString(), то и будет падать, так как в число этот метод не преобразует Float.parseFloat();

Comment: то есть, вместо Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString()); нужно описать метод преобразования и осуществить проверку?

Comment: оберните в try ... catch и если не смогли сконвертить , то NumberBf  = 0